# Can I create global powershell PSWorkflowJob jobs that all users can see?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I want to write a powershell workflow that will run scripts, reboot and continue execute where it left off. Not when a user logs on, but when the computer reboots (so non-interactively).

The challenge is that it needs to run locally. Windows makes this infuriatingly difficult.

What I have done so far is create a workflow that runs as a job (PSWorkflowJob).

In the middle of the workflow it runs restart-computer with the -wait switch

Then I create a scheduled task that runs at startup which resumes that workflow

The problem is that tasks cannot run at startup unless they store credentials or run as the local system. I don't want to pass admin creds at all in this script so I run the task as the local system.

When the computer reboots that task fires, but it can't find the job because the job was created by the local admin.

```
workflow Resume_Workflow
{

    PowerShell.exe -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\somescript.ps1'

    Restart-Computer -Wait

    PowerShell.exe -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\someotherscript.ps1'

}

$taskName = 'Continue_Workflow'
#Pass code directly to powershell.exe to avoid creating another .ps1 file
$PSCode = @'
-NoProfile -command "& powershell.exe {
Import-Module PSWorkflow;
Resume-Job -Name new_resume_workflow_job -Wait;
}"
'@

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument $PSCode
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:30
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Compatibility Win8
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId SYSTEM `
    -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest

$definition = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Principal $principal `
    -Settings $settings -Description "Run $($taskName) at startup" `
    -Trigger $trigger

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -InputObject $definition

# Execute the workflow as a PS job (PSWorkflowJob)
Resume_Workflow -AsJob -JobName new_resume_workflow_job
```

Comment: I suppose I could a task as the admin then create a startup task that runs as system which starts the admin task which will have access to the job?